# How to remove common item from list of dictionaries after grouping

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, group-by

I have a list of dictionaries like below. I want to group the dictionaries based on grade, and convert the list of dictionaries to single dictionaries with key as grade value and value as list of dictionaries

Input:

```
[
    {'name':'abc','mark':'99','grade':'A'},
    {'name':'xyz','mark':'90','grade':'A'},
    {'name':'123','mark':'70','grade':'C'},
]
```

I want my output like below:

```
{
    A: [ {'name': 'abc','mark':'99'}, {'name': 'xyz','mark':'90'} ],
    C: [ {'name': '123','mark':'70'} ]
}
```

I tried `sorted` and `groupby`; but not able to remove grade from dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop with [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
l = [{'name':'abc','mark':'99','grade':'A'}, 
     {'name':'xyz','mark':'90','grade':'A'},
     {'name':'123','mark':'70','grade':'C'},
    ]

out = {}

for d in l:
    # avoid mutating the original dictionaries
    d = d.copy() 
    # get grade, try to get the key in "out"
    # if the key doesn't exist, initialize with an empty list
    out.setdefault(d.pop('grade'), []).append(d)
    
print(out)
```

Output:

```
{'A': [{'name': 'abc', 'mark': '99'},
       {'name': 'xyz', 'mark': '90'}],
 'C': [{'name': '123', 'mark': '70'}],
}
```